# char Array within int Array

Tags: arrays, char

```
  String s = "abcdeffa"      

  char[] input1 = s.toCharArray();

  int[] freq = new int[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++)
      freq[input1[i]]++;
```

I do not understand the `freq[input[i]]++;` part. freq is a int [] but how it can store chari in freq [] array.

Can anyone explain how `freq[input1[i]]++;` works? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code should give an out of bound exception because `input[i]` returns the character code. So `freq[input[0]]` would be `freq[97]` (`'a'`'s ASCII code is 97) which is out of bounds because your array can only take 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will you ArrayIndexOutBound Exception. Because it will convert the corresponding char to ASCII value but your array size is only 10 so it will give you ArrayIndexOutBound  Exception.